# Magento 1.7.0.2 When I search for a product with quotation marks in it, it always adds a backslash before the quotes

Tags: magento-1.7, product, admin, catalogsearch, search-terms

My shop is run in Magento 1.7.0.2.

Let's say that I have a product that is listed as `5" Product`. If I search for that product from the backend admin area, the search will change to `5\" Product`.

Of course, this leads to the product not being found and didn't occur at all before a month ago.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running PHP 5.3 with [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.

This feature was a terrible decision from the early days of PHP. The idea was to escape every input by default to prevent SQL injections. But not only did it *not* prevent SQL injections, it also introduces undesired behavior in every application that does not expect this setting to be turned on.

It was finally removed in PHP 5.4 and I recommend to update your PHP version to at least 5.5 as soon as possible. Security support for 5.3 has ended 2014 and will end in 2015 for 5.4.

In the meantime, read: [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)